# Ability to use Bootstrap 3 grid system to specify width of select element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following `<select>` element as follows:

```
<select id="statusSelect" style="width:175px" class="form-control" name="statusCode">
```

However, someone has just told me that this can cause dynamic exceptions on hidden elements. My question is this: How can I use Bootstrap 3's Grid system to specify the width of the `<select>` element. I have tried the following:

```
<select id="statusSelect" class="form-control col-md-2" name="statusCode">
```

But, unfortunately, using `col-md-2` or even `col-md-4` does not change the width of the `<select>` element. So, can anyone help me to see how I can use Bootstrap 3's grid classes to specify the width of the `<select>` drop-down box.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what you have tried to change in bootstrap ? does it show any error if you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the classes to an wrapping div.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <select id="statusSelect" class="form-control" name="statusCode">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`col-md-2` does not change the width because `form-control` overwrite the `width` property because it has `width: 100%`

you can add class `col-md-2` without `form-control`

```
<select id="statusSelect" class="form-control col-md-2" name="statusCode">
```

or add the `col-md-2` to the parent like @trieber answer