# Twitter bootstrap grid - columns per row amount gets smaller if img is in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have 4 columns per row using [twitter bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

I have ran into a problem, where the amount of columns per row gets smaller, if I put my image inside a div when the page gets resized or is too small.

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/189/)

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />  
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />         
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see how there are **two** columns per row, not 4 because the page is too small for it, okay that's fine.

But I can't just have the img tag, I need it wrapped in a div in order to implement this design:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/1782577875acd356dd8f3d436c96b7e5.png))</sub>

So I wrapped them in a div, and take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/188/)

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="col-lg-3" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />   
        </div>
```

After I added them in a div, each, I only get one column per row.

Why is that happening and how can I prevent this?

Comment: You don't put col class on the image, you put it on a div and then you put the image inside the div. Please visit the docs at GetBootstrap.com. Images need to have the class `img-responsive` so that they size down with the percentages of the columns.

Comment: The solution is the same as in possible duplicate [Ability to use Bootstrap 3 grid system to specify width of select element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113523/ability-to-use-bootstrap-3-grid-system-to-specify-width-of-select-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

12 column row will include 4 3 column containers and not 5...please read the documentation on the grid http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Since Bootstrap is fluid and responsive you will see from reading the documentation that you can adjust the columns per breakpoint provided that they still add up to 12. There's also a thumbnail component, which may work for you:http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Notice the class `img-responsive` on the image. Here is an example that will be 4 fluid columns from very small viewports to very large because it uses `col-xs-*`. You can use `col-sm-*` for min-width 768px, `col-md-*` for min-width 992px, and `col-lg-*` for min-width 1200px, you can also adjust this with the customizer at GetBootstrap.com or or use LESS from the core.

**http://jsbin.com/zezuje/1/edit**

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.swansea.ca/images/sample-ad-270x270.jpg" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the code again and fix your answer. He doesn't have divs for his columns, he has put the class on the image and he has forgotten the class for the image. Read the bootstrap docs, this is completely wrong

Comment: Edited my question, my bad didn't copy the right part from jsFiddle.

Comment: @Kinnza Yes I did that too, I don't want to do it because then images wont resize. Now doesn't matter what, your content will lose width instead of going under each other on small screens. i want it to be responsive.

Comment: And I don't want 5 per row, only 4. But if the page is too small, it will be 2 per row, but if it's too small for 2 then 1. Responsively

Comment: something like this: img {width: 100%; height: auto;}

Comment: @Kinnza Ah I see, but what if  I want the whole div content to resize? look at the image example in my question, can this whole div be resized?

Comment: @BenBeri -- these questions are not necessary if you read the docs. I updated the code and added the demo: http://jsbin.com/zezuje/1/edit

Comment: @Kinnza I corrected your answer, please read the Bootstrap docs. It is out of the box set up for this provided that the correct classes are added.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer It seems like you guys are misunderstanding me. I don't want the images to resize always. If the window is way too small, then reduce the images per row. I want to do that to prevent the text under thumbnails become messy, check out http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/192/ and make the window of the jsfiddle output very small. You will see the 66 and 76 numbers will go under the text.

Comment: You can use a mixture of responsive utility classes and the column classes to address that, or use server side sniffing, or jQuery. Here's the infor for the the utility classes http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities